# Check multiple variables (columns) for a value in each row with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a new column based on if a value appears in one of 30+ columns.

Here is the example data:

```
df <- read.table(text =
"ACT_1   ACT_2    ACT_3 ACT_4 ACT_5 ACT_6  ACT_7
DBA     ABC     ABC    ABC    ABC    ABC       ABC
ABC     DBA     ABC    ABC    ABC    ABC       ABC
ABC     ABC     ABC    ABC    ABC    ABC       ABC",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would like to check all the columns that contain "ACT" in there name and create a new column that is binary 1 - if "DBA" is in the row and 0 - if it is not.  I would like to use dplyr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `base R`, we use `grep` to subset the columns that start with "ACT" (or `startsWith`), check if it is equal to "DBA" to create a logical matrix, then get the `rowSums`, convert it to logical `vector` by checking the count of TRUE elements greater than 0. This logical vector is converted to binary with `as.integer` (or `+`)

```
df$newCol <- +(rowSums(df[grep("^ACT", names(df))] == "DBA") > 0)
df$newCol
#[1] 1 1 0
```

---

Or another `base R` approach would be to use `Reduce` with `lapply`

```
df$newCol <- +(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[grep("^ACT", names(df))], `==`, "DBA")))
```

NOTE: Both the solutions are vectorized

---

Or using `tidyverse` without any reshaping

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
      mutate(newCol = map(., ~.x == "DBA") %>% 
                        reduce(`|`) %>%
                        as.integer)
#  ACT_1 ACT_2 ACT_3 ACT_4 ACT_5 ACT_6 ACT_7 newCol
#1   DBA   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC      1
#2   ABC   DBA   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC      1
#3   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC      0
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, newCol := +(Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, `==`, "DBA")))]
```

In the example, there is only 'ACT' columns.  If there are other columns, make sure to specify in `.SDcols` with the `grep` as showed in the first solution

#### Benchmarks

```
#data
df1 <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), 1e6), ]
```

-base R

```
system.time(+(rowSums(df1[grep("^ACT", names(df1))] == "DBA") > 0))
# user  system elapsed 
#  0.319   0.101   0.419 
system.time(+(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df1[grep("^ACT", names(df1))], `==`, "DBA"))))
# user  system elapsed 
#  0.152   0.029   0.179 

system.time(as.integer(apply(df1[grep("^ACT", names(df1))] == "DBA", 1, any)))
# user  system elapsed 
#  5.200   0.177   5.344
```

-tidyverse

```
system.time({df1 %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  gather(key, value, starts_with("ACT")) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(flag = as.integer(any(value == "DBA"))) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-row)})
#  user  system elapsed 
# 42.750   4.378  47.202 

system.time({
 df1 %>% 
          mutate(newCol = map(., ~.x == "DBA") %>% 
                            reduce(`|`))
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.188   0.016   0.203
```

-data.table

```
system.time({
   setDT(df1)[, newCol := +(Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, `==`, "DBA")))]
})
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.152   0.011   0.163
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method which involves reshaping using `dplyr`/`tidyr` would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  gather(key, value, starts_with("ACT")) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(flag = as.integer(any(value == "DBA"))) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-row)

# A tibble: 3 x 8
#   flag ACT_1 ACT_2 ACT_3 ACT_4 ACT_5 ACT_6 ACT_7
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     1 DBA   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC  
#2     1 ABC   DBA   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC  
#3     0 ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC
```

---

Or in base R, we can also use `apply`

```
df$flag <- as.integer(apply(df[grep("^ACT", names(df))] == "DBA", 1, any))
```